# Get-WmiObject returns with Access Denied error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to edit a registry value on a remote VM running Windows 7.
I am using the following code to edit it:

```
$password = "<password>" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "<username>"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

$hklm = 2147483650
$path = "SOFTWARE\crat\ler"
$key = "HostAddress"

$wmi = Get-WmiObject -List "StdRegProv" -Namespace root\default -ComputerName <IPAddress> -Credential $credential
if($wmi)
{
  $value = ($wmi.GetStringValue($hklm,$path,$key)).svalue
  Write-Host "Registry Value: $value"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Failed to get registry value"
}
```

The registry key path and credential are all correct but still I am getting the following error message:

```
Get-WmiObject : Could not get objects from namespace root\default. Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At D:\workspace\scripts\Update.ps1:29 char:8
+ $wmi = Get-WmiObject -List "StdRegProv" -Namespace root\default -Comp ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : INVALID_NAMESPACE_IDENTIFIER,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. Why do you think you have access? Can you open other RPC connections to the remote computer?

Comment: @vrdse I am pretty new to powershell. Can you provide a reference as to how to check my accessibility to the remote machine(which you said by using other RPC) ?

Comment: @Monku - try `Test-Connection` for simple connectivity. then use `Test-WSMan` to test for using windows remote management. those are the usual culprits. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I ran the command `Test-Connection -Source  <IpAddressOfMachineIAmOn> -ComputerName <IpAddressOfRemoteMachine> -Credential $credential`

It gives the error `Test-Connection : User credentials cannot be used for local connections`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Get-WmiObject does not use WSMAN but RPC.

Comment: @Monku can you run `compmgmt.msc` against the remote computer? Those two use the same mechanism. Furthermore, I suggest to try hostname instead of the IP address. If IP address is used, you can only authenticate with `NTLM` but not `Kerberos`, which might cause issues, depending on you environment.

Comment: @vrdse what am I looking in `compmgmt.msc` ?

Comment: @vrdse - ah! thank you for that info ... i misunderstood something i read. [*grin*]

Comment: @Monku - so ... don't use it? [*grin*] the test connection process is just PING, so all you are doing is testing if the source system can ping the target system.

Comment: The error states `INVALID_NAMESPACE_IDENTIFIER`. Better use `-Namespace "root/default"` (forward slash and quoted)